# Continuous functions and Neural Networks

Tags: continuity, neural-networks

Is there any continuous function $\phi$ such that $\phi(\cos x) = \sin x$ over $[0,2\pi)$? If so, could you give me an example?

I stumbled across this problem after trying to train a single layer neural network to do the same thing as my purported continuous function. By the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) I figured that if I can't train the neural net (training error is very high) it means there isn't a continuous function there to approximate the neural net towards. 
NN are dense in the space of continuous functions. 
Any thoughts?

EDIT: If it's relevant, I trained a radial basis function neural net.

Comment: What's the purpose of the subscript $0$ ?

Comment: Are you asking about the existence of a continuous function $\phi$ such that $\phi(\cos x)=\sin x$ over $[0,2\pi)$ ?

Comment: There is no purpose for the subscript 0. Yes. That's my question, @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be such a function because $\phi(\cos(2\pi-x))=\phi(\cos x)$ while $\sin(2\pi-x)=-\sin x$.